# how do I fetch the Facebook secret key from the apikey I have?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I have the app's api key with me and not the secret key. is there a way to fetch dynamically using  restapi/fql or another way to fetch it?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't.

The `API Key` is public, so suppose if this was possible then any user could have the `APP secret` of any app.